# how to test equivalence of a string in a row with the next row value in asp.net mvc5 html table

Tags: html, asp.net

Given this piece of code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
  {

    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ObjectiveDescription)
      </td>
      ...
```

How do I test whether `item.ObjectiveDescription` in the next row is equal to the previous on such that I can replace it with an empty string if equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You could always store the previous value in a variable and check against that.

Untested so the picky Razor syntax may be a bit off but here's the general idea ...

```
@{ var priorValue = string.Empty; }

@foreach (var item in Model)
  {

    <tr>
      <td>
        @if (!item.ObjectiveDescription == priorValue) {
           Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ObjectiveDescription)
          }
        @{ priorValue = item.ObjectiveDescription; }
      </td>
  ...
```